# Upgrading a .NET application that uses Crystal, and is installed using ClickOnce

Tags: crystal-reports, clickonce

I've seen [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971651/net-clickonce-not-installing-prerequisite-files) on upgrading from a previous version of Visual Studio to VS 2008, that is distributed using ClickOnce.  I'm wondering about going from VS 2008 to VS 2010.  We used Crystal Reports XI Release 2, back when we wrote that original app.  Now I'd like to upgrade it to VS 2010.  However, on a previous project we also had to upgrade Crystal to Crystal Reports for VS 2010.  if I update this project to VS 2010, I'm assuming I'll be forced to upgrade the version of Crystal as well.  What issues do I face, upgrading an older version of a .NET app from .NET 3.5 SP1 to .NET 4, going from CR 11 R 2, to CR for VS 2010, and is deployed using ClickOnce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we upgraded the prerequisites of our ClickOnce applications, we changed the deployment accordingly and published it to a new URL. Then we took the old version of the application and added code to it so it would uninstall itself and then invoke the new installation from the new URL. This worked like a charm. You get your new prerequisites installed (if needed), and the app is installed with its new target framework (etc).

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx) about certificate expirations has the code for doing the uninstall/reinstall. We've used it several times and it worked great. It even clicks OK on the uninstall dialog for the ClickOnce app. We even used a variant of this code to do an uninstall/reinstall of a VSTO application.

Comment: I hadn't thought of publishing to a different URL.  Good idea!  I'll check over the rest of what you've suggested, too.  Basically, it sounds like what we should do is branch the code, having the old code do an uninstall of itself, and the redirect the user to the new installation, whereas the new code will just pick up using .NET 4.0, etc.  Thanks!